# How to identify a profile password policy linked to a profile easily?

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api, profile, passwords

I would like to know an easy way to fetch the profile password policy attached to a profile.

I know the metadata api "profilepasswordpolicy" which is useful to retrieve settings of a policy, but where is the link between this policy and the profile, for example a field of the profile that could specify this policy.

I dont find any api to catch this link between those two.

I saw that there is a field profile is the profilepasswordpolicy, but it's the profile fullName in lowercase, and if we have two profile for example Admin and ADMIN (my client has both), I can't identify which profile is concerned in this policy.I dont know why it's in lowercase, it's really a bad idea from SF devs.

And it's not a good way to scan all password policies to reverse search the profile related.